# Create layer of any shape in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I create a layered model like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

a = np.full((9,10),1)
a[:5,] = 1
a[5:10,] = 2
print(a)
plt.imshow(a)

>>> Output:
[[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]
 [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]
 [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]
 [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]]
```

The result of plt.imshow() shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjAJg.png).

Lets consider that I have two vectors:

```
x = np.linspace(0,10,10)
z = np.random.uniform(0, 9, size=(1,9)).round(0)
```

Where x is a row, and z is a column (coordinates if we keep it simple).

How do I change this numpy array in a way, that I assign `value=10` to corresponding pairs of x and z (x[i],z[i]) = 1? So in the end I can have something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpY2L.png).

Comment: In principle you can do something like this: `a[x,z] = 1`. However, there are several things that you would have to consider. (1) `x` and `z` have to be integers and have to be within `a.shape` -- right now they are neither. (2) `np.full` already produces a matrix full of ones, so the assignment has no net effect. (3) even if you change it to 'a[x,z]=2', you still won't get the picture you desire, because your x-z pairs only define a path, not an area.

Comment: I reckon the path would be a good start :) Good point about value, I have changed it to 10, to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to index `numpy` arrays using `iterables`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

a = np.full((10,10),1)

x = np.arange(10)
z = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(1,10))

a[x,z] = 2

plt.imshow(a)
plt.show()
```

Note how I use `astype(int)` instead of `round` (**EDIT**: it is even better to use `randint` from the start -- thanks to kazemakase for the comment) and how I adjusted the range of `a`. I also replaced `linspace` with `arange`, as the latter is guaranteed to produce integers.

The result looks something like this:

[image: result of code]

Comment: @kazemakase good point -- I just copied over the code from the OP and apparently stopped thinking at that point. I'll fix it in the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It took my a couple of days!